# Mysql performance: extra field or many joins

Tags: mysql, performance, join, field

I’ve been working on this for a long time. After ‘solving' the problem, it is still on my mind.

My database has many relationships (all many to one) between tables. I will sketch a situation:

```
users 
projects (user_id, …)
forms (project_id, …)
form_elements (form_id, …)
form_element_lists (form_element_id, …)
```

If somebody updates a row of the form_element_lists table I need to perform a check to make sure that the user is allowed to edit that specific row. My first thought would be to make 4 left joins.

But because updating the rows happens very often I added a ‘user_id’ to every table, so a security check can be performed without any join query. Else I would sometimes even have to make 6 join to find the user id.

After some sleepless nights I want to propose this question to you: is it better (for performance and database design) to make 6 joins, or to add an user_id field to all the tables?

Comment: de-normalization is certainly a controversial topic. Both camps have valid arguments

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Is the following thought correct: added a field to every table can improve the performance. And using joins is a more clear way to design a database?

Comment: Since you've already denormalized your db, you could actually do a performance comparison yourself quite easily and answer the question yourself. I'd be interested in the result :^)

Comment: Miseur Moos, you can answer your own question, with an Answer like that below, and get an immediate upvote from me. Just couch it as you know it is not ideal by a country mile, but there are times when de-norm is justified or at least arguable. Then catch up on that sleep :> ...Oh, and publish your schema, perhaps you need a peer-review on the indexing in place